# Blocks for Passing Data between VC's - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

I'm using blocks to pass data from a view controller, VC3, which appears within a modal view that is pushed by VC1. The modal displayed is VC2, and it shows VC3 before being dismissed.

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when using the blocks.

Below is the code.

VC1.m

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.VC2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];

VC3 *VC3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];

VC3.onDismiss = [^(VC3 *sender, NSMutableArray *details)
{
    //set stuff here

} copy];
[self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

VC3.h

`@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^onDismiss)(VC3 *sender,   NSMutableArray* details);`

VC3.m

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   NSMutableArray *details = [NSMutableArray array];
    [details addObject:x];
    [details addObject:y];
    [details addObject:z];

    self.onDismiss(self, details);
}];
```

I've tried and failed to get this working a few times. If someone could help me with this, I would be really grateful.

Comment: you should check that a block isn't `nil` before calling it. If it is, it will crash when called.

Comment: @originaluser2 I've done that and it has stopped it from crashing, but now the block in VC1 is never called now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Block properties should be declared as `copy`

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^simpleBlock)(void);
   ```
2. Then, when passing the block, don't call the copy method on it.

   ```
   VC3.onDismiss = ^(VC3 *sender, NSMutableArray *details)
   {
       // do stuff here
   };
   ```
3. Finally, you should check if the block is not `nil` before executing it.

#### Problem

It looks like you're invoking the block after the view controller was dismissed. This means you're trying to access deallocated memory. Problem lays here:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   NSMutableArray *details = [NSMutableArray array];
    [details addObject:x];
    [details addObject:y];
    [details addObject:z];

    self.onDismiss(self, details);
}];
```

You dismiss the controller and then in completion handler you access it's property.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've done all those changes and am still getting the error!

Comment: Alright, I think I figured it out. Please check out updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a really good point. I've moved the self.onDismiss(self, details) call so that it is outside of the completion block, but it is still 'nil'. Perhaps its because I don't define it in the VC3.m? Or would that be an issue?